# Access companion object from case class (or vice-versa) using scala type macros

Tags: scala, types, macros, companion-object

I'm trying to create a value on a companion object based on the fields of a case class.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
case class A(
  val a: Int,
  val b: String
) extends MyTypeMacro
```

I'd like for this to add to add a value to its companion object...

```
object A { 
  //Generate...
  val c: B = //Code value derived from case class fields...
}
```

Because companion objects and classes have access to each other, shouldn't
I be able to accomplish this by accessing the companion object from within the case class type macro?

Also... I'd like to add 'val c' whether object A is defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible yet. We're playing with something along these lines, but it's very early stage, so I can't say anything definitive.

Comment: any links, experiments, forks?